# Metodo old en un select

Tags: php, laravel

Estimados mi problema es el siguiente:
tengo un select que lo relleno con un foreach y aparte le agrue una opcion en disable selected para poder usar como placeholder. Lo que necesito es que al utilizar este select y hacer la busqueda, quede seleccionada la opcion que eligio el usuario, probe varias formas con el metodo old, y no se en que estoy fallando.

```
<select class="custom-select" name="category">
                            <option disabled selected>Selecciona una Categoría</option>
                            @foreach ($categories as $category)
                            <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que podrías formular mejor la pregunta, pero según lo que entiendo, quieres tener un valor seleccionado dentro del `<select>`

Si mencionas que probaste con `old()` supongo que es por una respuesta que viene con valores para este método, lo más probable sea porque hiciste una validación de la petición. Por lo que debes comparar el valor de `old('category')` cuando armas las `<option>`

```
<select class="custom-select" name="category">
    <option disabled selected>Selecciona una Categoría</option>
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ old('category') == $category->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Además puedes hacer una petición que contenga una variable, como ejemplo usaré `$variable`, donde si no existe un valor en `old()` prosigues a comparar el valor de `$variable` con el de `$category->id`, por lo que si ese valor coincide tambien la marcas como seleccionada.

```
<select class="custom-select" name="category">
    <option disabled selected>Selecciona una Categoría</option>
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ old('category') ? (old('category') == $category->id ? 'selected' : '') : ($category->id == $variable->id ? 'selected' : '') }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: probe haciendolo de la primera forma que expones, pero de esa manera siempre queda el primer elemento que tenga en el select ya que es un foreach.

Comment: Tienes que depurar si el valor de `old('category')` y `$category->id` coinciden, si te queda el primer valor es porque el `if` no está siendo `true` en ninguno de los siguientes elementos del foreach. Esto lo he implementado en muchos proyectos de Laravel con foreach dentro de select, por lo que la implementación tácnicamente funciona pero debes revisar los valores de tus variables.